# How to free a buffer malloc'd by a P/Invoked C function?

Tags: .net, pinvoke

The C library was compiled with MinGW and the exported function returns a malloc()'d buffer. It is responsibility of the caller to free() this buffer.

Is Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem compatible with malloc?

Is it possible to P/Invoke free() somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you export memory allocated with malloc, it needs to be freed with free from the same runtime as the malloc. You could export free from your DLL but that may not be the most elegant solution.

Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem is for use on memory allocated by the COM allocated. So you would use this in managed code to free memory allocated by an unmanaged call to CoTaskMemAlloc. This is a good solution to your problem.

Another answer suggests freeing memory with Marshal.FreeHGlobal which will work provided it was allocated with LocalAlloc. This is a rather tiresome API to use and I would always prefer the COM allocator for its convenience.

If you are exporting strings consider using a BSTR which is allocated by the COM allocator and can be marshalled automatically by the .net marshaller.

Comment: Is it safe exporting `free()`, directly or indirectly (wrapped as part of the public API)?

Comment: @vines You can certainly export free, I'd wrap it though. What safety are you concerned for?

Comment: As it is going to be called from another runtime context, it could mess things up, due to, say, some implementation details... Don't know, just have a vague warning feeling about it :)

Comment: @vines You just need to understand the rules and abide by them. In an ideal world you try to avoid getting into this scenario. But there are times when it is not avoidable.